# How to solve $\tan2x-\sin4x = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find $x$ in some trigonometric equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183619/how-to-find-x-in-some-trigonometric-equations)

How to solve these trigonometric equations?

$$\tan2x-\sin4x = 0$$

Comment: Why did you post the same equation of [your last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/183619/752)?

Comment: My hint and answer to the last question (as linked by Américo Tavares) give a method of solving this.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\sin4x=2\sin2x\cos2x$, and $\tan2x=\dfrac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}$. Now let $a=\sin2x$ and $b=\cos2x$, write your equation in terms of $a$ and $b$, and see what it tells you about $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

*Since this is a homework, some intermediate steps are omitted and left for you to work out.*

The identities you need are$^{\dagger}$
$$
\sin(4x) = \color{red}{2} \sin(2x) \cos(2x)\\
\tan(2x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}
$$
Substitute both in
$$ \tan(2x)-\sin(4x) = 0$$
to get
$$ (1 - 2 \cos^2(2x))\sin(2x) = 0  $$
which you should be able to factor into $3$ cases. Solve each case for $x.$

---

$^{\dagger}$ Fixed error thanks to  Thomas Andrews and David Mitra.

Comment: can u show me the step to get $$ (1 - 2 \cos^2(2x))\sin(2x) = 0 $$  ? I really don't know and what should i do next?

Comment: @dramasea If substitute as [Andrew said in his answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/183646/2468), you'll get $\cfrac {\sin 2x}{\cos 2x} = 2 \sin 2x \cos 2x.$ Now multiply both sides by $\cos 2x$ and factor.

Comment: As for the steps *after*, you have 3 cases: $\sin(2x) = 0,$ and two cases for $\cos^2(2x) = 1/2.$ Try to work them out.

Comment: I was wondering - did you choose your username after the character from the TV series [Scrubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrubs_%28TV_series%29)?